# How can I find where this function is continuous

Tags: multivariable-calculus, continuity

I need to find where this is continuous:
$$
f(x,y)=\begin{cases}
         0&\text{if}~\ x^2+y^2\le1\\
         x+y&\text{if}~\ x^2+y^2>1
       \end{cases}
$$

I have tried doing as such:
$$ z = 0 \implies y = -x$$
$$x^2 + x^2 = 1 \implies x = \pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$
But this isn't the right answer.

Comment: See [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference/5025#5025)

Comment: Outside the unit disk, it is smooth. Inside it is also smooth. So you really need to check what happens on the sphere.

Comment: Do you see that the function is continuous in the interior of the unit circle and outside of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function $f$ is discontinuous at the points of the set$$S=\left\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2\,\middle|\,x^2+y^2=1\right\}\setminus\left\{\left(\frac1{\sqrt2},-\frac1{\sqrt2}\right),\left(-\frac1{\sqrt2},\frac1{\sqrt2}\right)\right\}$$and only at those points. In fact:

- If $a^2+b^2<1$, then $f$ is continuous at $(a,b)$, since $(a,b)\in\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2\mid x^2+y^2<1\}$ and the restriction of $f$ to the open set $\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2\mid x^2+y^2<1\}$ is continuous ($f(x,y)=0$ there).
- If $a^2+b^2>1$, then $f$ is continuous at $(a,b)$, since $(a,b)\in\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2\mid x^2+y^2>1\}$ and the restriction of $f$ to the open set $\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2\mid x^2+y^2>1\}$ is continuous ($f(x,y)=x+y$ there).
- If $(a,b)=\left(\frac1{\sqrt2},-\frac1{\sqrt2}\right)$, then $f$ is continuous at $(a,b)$, since, for each $\varepsilon>0$, if you take $(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2$ such that $\bigl\|(x,y)-(a,b)\bigr\|<\frac\varepsilon2$, you have\begin{align}\bigl|f(x,y)-f(a,b)\bigr|&=\bigl|f(x,y)\bigr|\\&=\begin{cases}|x+y|&\text{ if }\|(x,y)\|>1\\0&\text{ if }\|(x,y)\|\leqslant1\end{cases}\\&=\begin{cases}\left|x-\frac1{\sqrt2}+y+\frac1{\sqrt2}\right|&\text{ if }x^2+y^2>1\\0&\text{ if }x^2+y^2\leqslant1\end{cases}\\&\leqslant\begin{cases}\left|x-\frac1{\sqrt2}\right|+\left|y+\frac1{\sqrt2}\right|&\text{ if }x^2+y^2>1\\0&\text{ if }x^2+y^2\leqslant1\end{cases}\\&<\varepsilon,\end{align}since $\left|x-\frac1{\sqrt2}\right|,\left|y+\frac1{\sqrt2}\right|<\frac\varepsilon2$.
- If $(a,b)=\left(-\frac1{\sqrt2},\frac1{\sqrt2}\right)$, then $f$ is continuous at $(a,b)$ for the same reason.
- In the remaining cases, $f$ is discontinuous at $(a,b)$, since $f(a,b)=0$, but, for each $\lambda>1$, $f(\lambda a,\lambda b)=\lambda(a+b)$, and$$\lim_{\lambda\to1^+}\lambda(a+b)=a+b\ne0=f(a,b).$$

Comment: Yes but in which points is the function continious. The solution should be $$(- \frac{\sqrt{2}{2}, \frac{\sqrt{2}{2}), (\frac{\sqrt{2}{2}, -\frac{\sqrt{2}{2})$$

Comment: The question does not ask *whether* the function is continuous.  It asks *where* it is continuous.

Comment: @XanderHenderson Indeed. I have edited my answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use polar coordinate: $x=r \cos\theta,~y=r\sin(\theta)$

To make it continuous on the circle, it requires:

$$\lim_{r\to1^+} r(\cos(\theta)+\sin(\theta))=0\Rightarrow \cos(\theta)+\sin(\theta)=0\Rightarrow\theta=\frac{3\pi}{4}~\text{or}~\frac{7\pi}{4}$$

Converting to Cartesian coordinate,

$$A\left(\frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right),~~~B\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)$$

The function is continuous on $\{(x,y)|x^2+y^2<1\cup x^2+y^2>1\cup A\cup B \} $

Comment: Those are the points on the unit circle where the function is continuous, but it is also continuous everywhere else

Comment: Yes, I have edited it. @Angelica